# How can I run a function while audio is playing randomized in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

(Please bear with me if it seems super-obvious, I'm an absolute beginner, and I'm stuck.)

I built this: https://github.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io

The idea: every time you click on the face, and it plays a random sound from the array, and it also animates.

The problem: at the moment it does that but with 2 separate event listeners. Animates on mouseover/leave (I'm swapping files in query using classes) and it plays on click. Not ideal.

How can I fix it so that both things happen for the same event?

My only thought is to swap to the gif file for as long as the sound is playing, and once it's done it swaps back to png. Is that possible?

Thank yoooou.

Comment: If you want it to happen on the same event bind it to the same event? I'm not sure if you want it to be on hover or on click?

Comment: @Tommie My plan too initially. But then it'd overwrite the css showing the gif and not revert back (hence the mouseover/mouseleave solution).

Comment: So you basically want it to animate + play sound when the user click? One could set it up like that.

Comment: I've given you an example on how you could solve this. Do comment if there is something wrong with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that binds all this to the click handler and also checks if/when the audio has stopped playing using `onended` and then resets the face to its orginial css-class (your png).

```js
var audioFiles = [
 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io/master/assets/sounds/01.m4a',
 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io/master/assets/sounds/02.m4a',
 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io/master/assets/sounds/03.m4a',
 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io/master/assets/sounds/04.m4a',
 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io/master/assets/sounds/05.m4a',
 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io/master/assets/sounds/06.m4a',
 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io/master/assets/sounds/07.m4a',
 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/aplustardcrocodile/aplustardcrocodile.github.io/master/assets/sounds/08.m4a',
];

var face = $('#face'),
 audio = $('#audio')[0],
 isPlaying = false;

face.on('click', function(){
 
 if( !isPlaying ){
  isPlaying = true;

  // toggle class to change image
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  // get random from audioFiles
  var currentAudio = audioFiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * audioFiles.length)];

  // set new random audio as src
  audio.src = currentAudio;

  // ..then play it
  audio.currentTime = 0; // 0 always make sure its reset
  audio.play();
 }
})

// check when audio is complete
audio.onended = function(){

 // reset isPlaying
 isPlaying = false;
 
 // remove active-class from face
 face.removeClass('active');

};
```

```css
body { padding: 1%; background: aliceblue; width: 472px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; }
#face {
 background: url('https://aplustardcrocodile.github.io/assets/images/Face.png') no-repeat;
 width: 472px; height: 665px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: transform .5s ease;
}

#face:hover { opacity: .9; }


#face.active {
 opacity:1;
 background: url('https://aplustardcrocodile.github.io/assets/images/Face-loop.gif') no-repeat;
 transform: rotateZ(5deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- face container -->
<div id="face"></div>

<!-- audio element -->
<audio id="audio"></audio>
```

---

#### See/edit on JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/tommiehansen/svkeebgy/4/

---

Do note that there will be a lag for when you load the next sound if the user has not cached. A solution to that would be to simply preload all the audiofiles inline and then selecting one of these to play instead of using files in the js array. Other measures can be taken as well, but that is another question. :)

Comment: Btw -- here's a sample that also uses `onplay` handle to only then toggle the `active` class: https://jsfiddle.net/tommiehansen/svkeebgy/6/

Comment: Great, happy to help! :)